# select dynamic tab immediately upon new tab creation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/ujUu2/

```
var num_tabs = $("div#tabs ul li").length + 1;

        $("div#tabs ul").append(
            "<li><a href='#tab" + num_tabs + "'>#" + num_tabs + "</a></li>"
        );
$("div#tabs").append(
            "<div id='tab" + num_tabs + "'>#" + num_tabs + "</div>"
        );
        $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
```

the new tabs syntax is so complicated (after 1.9 upgrade)..

one more question, 1.9 onward the remove method had been depreceated, so if I want to remove a particular tab, should I use remove() to remove the tab element and then the appended div (content)? that sound un-practical..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in the end of `$("button#add-tab").click(function()`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ujUu2/43/)

```
$('a[href=#tab'+num_tabs+']').click(); //click new tab link to make it active
```

or you can use `active` option

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ujUu2/44/)

```
$("div#tabs").tabs("refresh").tabs({ active:num_tabs - 1});
```

Comment: There is a option named "active" that is made for this purpose. What if another handler is on clicking tabs ?

Comment: @TCHdvlp added active option also

Answer (score 1):

Use the [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) option

```
$("div#tabs").tabs("refresh").tabs('option', 'active', num_tabs - 1);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4zc9B/)